# Django resolving single underscore as a related field parameter

Tags: django

Consider my model:

```
class CampUserInvitation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    camp = models.ForeignKey('events.Camp')
    user_accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This model above is an intermediary model for m2m relationship between Camp and User:

```
class Camp(Event):
    invited = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User',
                                 through='events.CampUserInvitation')
    def get_users_signed(self):
        return (self.invited
                .filter(user_accepted__exact=True)
                .filter(user_accepted_timestamp__lte=self.invitation_deadline)
            )
```

when I want to filter the queryset of all Users by only those that have user_accepted field set to True (in the above get_users_signed method)

```
self.invited.filter(user_accepted__exact=True)
```

I get:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'user_accepted' into field. Choices are: <bunch of attributes of the User class>
```

Why does django think that 'accepted' is a parameter of the user? Wasn't I supposed to use double underscore for that?

Comment: You are missing the `ForeignKey` reference to `Camp` table in the through table `CampUserInvitation`

Comment: I excluded that for the sake of brevity, the models are more complex than that. But you're right, I should put it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not what's happening at all.

`invited` is a reference to the User model, so when you filter on invited, that's the model you filter on. If you need to filter on CampUserInvitation, you need to use the reverse relationship from the ForeignKey on that model:

```
 self.campuserinvitation_set.filter(user_accepted=True)
```

**Edit after comment** This might work:

```
self.invited.filter(campuserinvitation__user_accepted=True)
```

Comment: But that will give me a bunch of CampUserInvitations. I want to get Users for which the invitations with user_accepted=True for this event exist. I understand I can iterate now through this queryset and get them as a list of python objects.. however, is there a way how to filter queryset of related m2m field directly by the attributes of the intermediary model?